# Get desktop shell access by wired connection from Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, ssh, shell, raspberry-pi, remote-control

Today I asked my self if this was possible: Connect a Raspberry Pi to a desktop PC (Ideally to the motherboard, so that the Pi can be hidden inside the case) and then connect he Pi the the Internet and access it from a remote machine. I can easily setup a SSH server or reverse shell on the Pi so I can get remote access, no problem. But I want to know, if there is any way that I can connect the Pi to the desktop, so that I can execute code on the desktop from the Pi.

I think this would be a funny project, maybe also a last result to get back you desktop if it has been stolen?

I did do my homework, I searched the web for "Connect Raspberry Pi to desktop PC" and search strings like that, but only remote desktop guides showed up. I did the other day find something that may have related to this, but that was while searching for something else, and I was not able to find the site again.

I made a diagram of the ideal setup. I hope any of you can give me some knowledge or point me in the right direction.

[image: Diagram of ideal setup]

**What I want to generally accomplish:**

1. Get a wired connection between a desktop mother board and a Raspberry PI.
2. Connect the Raspberry Pi to the outside world and SSH/reverse shell into it.
3. Execute shell commands on the desktop using the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Which model do you have?

Comment: I'm planning on buying the new model 3, the one with Wi-Fi. Haven't bought it yet though. :)